# Converting mac address to IPv6 link local address in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ipv6

How can I convert a mac address like `00:16:3e:15:d3:a9` into an IPv6 link local address (as modified EUI-64, like `fe80::216:3eff:fe15:d3a9`) in Ruby?

So far, I have the following steps:

```rb
mac = "00:16:3e:15:d3:a9"
mac.delete!(':')        # Delete colons
mac.insert(6, 'fffe')   # Insert ff:ee in the middle
mac = mac.scan(/.{4}/)  # Split into octets of 4
```

The [next step](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_IPv6InterfaceIdentifiersandPhysicalAddressMapping-2.htm) would be to flip the sixth bit of the first octet, which I'm having trouble with.

Comment: The problem you are having is that you are trying to do that using text. Both IP and MAC addresses are binary numbers. and you can simply use a bitwise OR to set the U/L bit of the MAC address as a binary number. Then, you can convert back to text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your main problem: Ruby is an object-oriented language. You create programs by manipulating rich, structured objects, more precisely by telling rich, structured objects to manipulate themselves.

You, however, are manipulating `String`s. Now, of course, `String`s are also objects in Ruby, but they are objects which represent *text*, they are not objects which represent *IP addresses* or EUIs.

You should *at least* treat IP addresses or EUIs as *numbers*, not as text, but really, you should treat them as rich, structured IP address objects or EUI objects.

Ruby actually comes with [a library for manipulating IP addresses](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/) as part of its [standard library](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/).

Here's an example of what it would look like to treat those addresses as numbers and/or objects:

```rb
require 'ipaddr'

eui48 = '00-16-3E-15-D3-A9'
# eliminate all delimiters, note that only ':' is not enough; the standard is '-', but '.' is also sometimes used
eui48 = eui48.gsub(/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/, '')
# parse the EUI-48 as a number
eui48 = eui48.to_i(16)

# split the EUI-48 into the OUI and the manufacturer-assigned parts
oui, assigned = eui48.divmod(1 << 24)

# append 16 zero bits to the OUI
left = oui << 16
# add the standard bit sequence
left += 0xfffe
# append 24 zero bits
left <<= 24

# now we have an EUI-64
eui64 = left + assigned

# flip bit index 57 to create a modified EUI-64
modified_eui64 = eui64 ^ 1 << 57

# the prefix for link-local IPv6 addresses is fe80::/10, link-local addresses are in the fe80::/64 network
prefix = IPAddr.new('fe80::/64')

# the suffix is based on our modified EUI-64
suffix = IPAddr.new(modified_eui64, Socket::AF_INET6)

# the final result is the bitwise logical OR of the prefix and suffix
link_local_ipv6 = prefix | suffix

# the IP address library knows how to correctly format an address according to RFC 5952 Section 4
link_local_ipv6.to_s
#=> 'fe80::216:3eff:fe15:d3a9'
```

Comment: What is the significance of `<< 112` when creating the prefix? How could you pass an arbitrary prefix there?

Comment: The prefix for link-local addresses is `0xfe80`, which is 16 bits long, so you have to append another 112 bits to get 128 bits.

Comment: Actually, come to think of it, the prefix is only 10 bits, so to be 100% correct, it should be `0x3fa << 118`.

Comment: It looks like `IPAddr.new('fe80::/10', Socket::AF_INET6)` also works.

Comment: Thanks. Worked that in. Actually, you don't even need to specify the address family, it can be detected automatically.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, the IPv6 Link-Local address prefix is `fe80::/10`, but IPv6 Link-Local addresses are required to have the next 54 bits set to `0`, so Link-Local addresses are in the `fe80::/64` network. See _[RFC 4291, IP Version 6 Addressing Architecture, Section 2.5.6. Link-Local IPv6 Unicast Addresses](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4291#section-2.5.6)_.